# C# Show Photos of a specified folder in listview

Tags: c#, listview, printing, photo, preview

I would like to preview photos of a specified folder in a listview (folder is empty at beginning and later it gets 5-10 photos so listview should check the folder that photo is in it or not).

If I click on a photo shown in the listview, it should call a print procedure

Comment: what have you done till now ?

Comment: it's a part of a project.other parts is done. i had no idea how automatically photos be added to listview.just this. i will do other things alone

Comment: "how automatically photos be added to listview"  Either use a Timer and check the folder periodically, or use the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) control to detect when the folder has changed.

Answer (score 1):

finally i did it

private void loadimages()
        {

```
        files.Clear();
        imageList1.Images.Clear();
        listView1.Clear();
        string[] part1 = null, part2 = null, part3 = null;

        part1 = Directory.GetFiles(p, "*.jpg");
        part2 = Directory.GetFiles(p, "*.jpeg");
        part3 = Directory.GetFiles(p, "*.bmp");


        for (int i = 0; i < part1.Length; i++)
        {
            imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(part1[i]));
            listView1.Items.Add("", i);
            files.Add(part1[i]);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < part2.Length; i++)
        {

            imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(part2[i]));
            listView1.Items.Add("", i);
            files.Add(part2[i]);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < part3.Length; i++)
        {

            imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(part3[i]));
            listView1.Items.Add("", i);
            files.Add(part3[i]);

        }
        check();
        PhotoPlace.Text = p;
    }
```